# How can apply a "filter filter" in a for instead using an "if" in Twig

Tags: twig

From the [deprecated](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html) page of Twig documentation:

> Adding an if condition on a for tag is deprecated in Twig 2.10. 
>   Use a filter filter or an "if" condition inside the "for" body instead (if
>   your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop)

If it's clear to me the part:

> an "if" condition inside the "for" body

In this way:

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users if user.active %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Instead this part it's not clear:

> Use a filter filter

Any example explaining how doing it *wrong* and doing it *right*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this way (taken from the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html)):

```
<ul>
    {% for user in users|filter(user => user.active) %}
        <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```